# Is there a way to detect at runtime if a library was statically linked?

Tags: linker, ld, dlsym

I have a situation where I distribute a library that uses symbol interposition to deal with some `stdlib.h` functions, e.g., `malloc`. I would normally just use the standard `psymbol = dlsym(RTDL_NEXT,"symbol")` technique [as described here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-s03/src/interposition/mymalloc.c).

I have some users that want to build statically linked binaries though, and `RTLD_NEXT` isn't valid in that context---`dlsym` doesn't just fail in that context, it exits with *RTLD_NEXT used in code not dynamically loaded*. I can force these users to use the `-Wl,--wrap,symbol` methodology [described here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-s03/src/interposition/mymalloc.c), and provide the appropriate `__real_symbol,_wrap_symbol` pair since they are using `pkg-config` to link to my library anyway.

It would be fine with me to always use the linker wrap solution, however I have a problem where one of my optional library dependencies (`Open MPI`) is also trying to wrap the same symbols, but is using the `RTLD_NEXT` approach---this appears to take precedence over the `ld` wrap option.

I can certainly implement both options, and statically select the `dlsym` approach when `Open MPI` is configured (`Open MPI` prevents `-static` linking anyway). The problem is that I'm not sure that this will be the only library trying to interpose on my symbols.

Is there a way that I can compile both options into my library (i.e., `__real_symbol` and `__wrap_symbol` for the `-static` link, and `symbol` and `*psymbol` for `dlsym`), force the `-Wl,--wrap,symbol` flags during static linking (through `pkg-config --static --cflags`), and dynamically check to see if `RTLD_NEXT` is currently available? This way I can build one library that works in both contexts.